# DelegateProtocol issue in multiple controller with same base class's cell's delegate call

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, tableview, protocols

Here i am facing issue with DelegeProtocol.

```
Class MainPagesVC : XLPageViewController<PagerDelegate>
{
    ....
    let page1: PageVC
    let page2: PageVC
    let page3: PageVC
}

Class PageVC : UIViewController {
    let tableView: UITableView
    ....
    cellForRowAt() {
        let cell = UploadCell..
        cell.delegate = self
        ....
    }
}
extension PageVC: CellDelegateProtocol {
    //In DelegateProtocol
    cellDelegateProcessDone() {
        //here reloading tableview for get updated data
        print(‘pageIndex:(currentPageIndex)’)
        //
    }
}


Class UploadCell: UITableViewCell {
    ....
    awakeFromNib(){
        self.lbl.text = self.getProgress()
    }
        
    //this process will call after done process, so not wasting time
    afterDoneProcess() {
        self.delegate.cellDelegateProcessDone()
    } 
}
```

- PageVC’s table view have cell with display upload process like 10%, 30% till 100%
- In every page’s viewWillApper call API for get different data, so I don’t want to make another screen for just list change.
- I am using **DelegateProtocol** for do some process in PageVC after done upload cell process.

Now the scenario is,

- First I am on **Page1** and tableview reload and UploadCell display with 10%.
- Now swipe to **Page2** and tableview reload and UploadCell display till 10%, because upload process display only for Page1, not updating for Page2 **(This is also issue)**.
- Now staying on Page2 till 100% of Page1's cell done.
- **Remember: I am on Page2 and process done for Page1 and I want to update something on Page2 with Page1’s cellDelegateProcessDone() method.**

**Now the issue is:**

- When I am on Page2 and process done for Page1 then delegate method call but for Page1, not for Page2,
- And It’s print “pageIndex:0”, still I am on Page2, it should display “pageIndex:1”
- Because in that delegate method if I want to do some reload part than currently only able to update for Page1, not for Page2 **(issue)**.
- It will resolve with NSNotification Observer, but I don’t want to use observer.

**Also know the issue**, what happen,
It’s not updating due to **cell.delegate = self**,

Because on Page1, it’s like **cell.delegate = Page1**, and for Page2 like **cell.delegate = Page2**,
So when I am on Page2 and once process done in Page1’s cell then it’s try to call like **self.Page1.cellDelegateProcessDone()** And it’s print with Page1, I also want to do some process on Page2. Like **self.Page2.cellDelegateProcessDone()**

I know, it’s might be little confusion flow, but I tried to explain I was faced.

So let me know if anyone have solution for this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can u check multicast delegate if that can help you somehow?

Comment: ok, i will check thanks!!